# Read YAML components from variable in groovy

Tags: groovy, scripting, jenkins-groovy

I have a code like below

```
import groovy.yaml.YamlSlurper
def configYaml = '''\
---
application: "Sample App"
users:
- name: "mrhaki"
  likes:
  - Groovy
  - Clojure
  - Java
- name: "Hubert"
  likes:
  - Apples
  - Bananas
connections:
- "WS1"
- "WS2"
'''
// Parse the YAML.
def config = new YamlSlurper().parseText(configYaml)
def data1 = "users"
def date2 = "name"

println config.users.likes // printing correct 
println config.$data1.$data2 // getting error
```

I need to print elements from users.name and I need to print it from variable form.
like "println config.$data1.$data2"

Comment: Note that you have a typo for `def date2 = "name"`

Comment: true, it should be likes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like below.

```
def config = new YamlSlurper().parseText(configYaml)
def data1 = "users"
def data2 = "name"

println config.users.likes
println config."$data1"."$data2"
```